# Dont remove filters in magento

Tags: magento

I Apply filter in magneto. But if I Click on any filter some filter are hide now I want to show all filter always.Any help will be **appreciated**.

Answer (score 1):

the part of code that hides other options located at `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php` this part.

```
if ($filter && strlen($text)) {
    $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
    $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
    $this->_items = array();
}
```

Overwrite this part in local pool.

Comment: i am using fme layred navi